# String to DateTime Convertion of 2013-05-04 13:12:20.123Z

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime

I need to output this string value (2013-05-04 13:12:20.123Z) to a valid Datetime on this format (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss).

I tried Convert.ToDateTime, DateTime.ParseExact, DateTime.Parse but its change my Hour to another one, actually I tried to understand what is happen under of hood, but I didn't!

Anyone can explain me what the compiler understand about this format? Convert.ToDateTime output the real value of this format?

Which is the best way to Parse it?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` might be a good place to start.

Comment: Do you mean you need to transform one date time string representation to another? What have you tried so far that isn't working? When you ask for "best way", you need to qualify with a "... for" - what is that? for preserving the date value? for readability? for performance?

Comment: Yes, I receive this in string format from a XML and if a convert it with DateTime.Parse its turn to other Hour, such: 2013-05-04 07:00:00;

Thanks for all negativation before ask me. #not

Comment: People are downvoting because you have shown no effort to solve this yourself. Perhaps you have made such an effort, but you have not **shown** it.

Comment: Yeah I dit it, here is my last choice. I tried every kind of format convertion.

Comment: Then why haven't you told us? And explain what didn't work? That would ensure people don't give you answers that you have already tried. Now, why not edit your question to add these _relevant_ details?

Comment: I just tried to do this question most simple as possible. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Z` at the end of the date string tells the parsing used in `DateTime.Parse` to treat the time as UTC.

That means that when you parse it locally, the result you get is in local time (which makes me guess you are at a `-05:00` timezone.

If you *must* have the exact same values in the `DateTime` instance, you can use `ParseExact` and treat the `Z` as a literal:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2013-05-04 13:12:20.123Z", 
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                    DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind)
```

Note, change the `DateTimeStuyles` to `RoundTripKind` as suggested by [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991191/string-to-datetime-convertion-of-2013-05-04-131220-123z/16991377?noredirect=1#comment24553806_16991377) by Matt.

Comment: Hmmkay, so the convertion is right, its just changed it to my timezone. Actually I'm on -03:00 timezone. How can I get the original value? Using an Invariant Culture will output the right value? I don't wanna convert it to my Timezone.

Comment: @FelipeKM - Well, it will use the timezone set on the computer it is on...

Comment: I don't wanna convert it to my Timezone, I just wanna convert it to a DateTime object but with the same HH:MM:SS values.

Comment: Let me add this workaround that I've found: DateTime.Parse(xml.Element("timestamp").Value).ToUniversalTime()

Comment: @FelipeKM - Well, yes, that's another option - convert a local time to a UTC one.

Comment: Actually, you would be better to use `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` so the result has the same values but has a `DateTimeKind.Utc` setting on its `.Kind` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**DateTime.ParseExact Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with correct format and you will Get `DateTime` as result.

Then you can call [**DateTime.ToString**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) with again your second format.

```
string input = "2013-05-04 13:12:20.123Z";
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffZ";

DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal ,out dt))
{
    var result = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Output is

> 04/05/2013 13:12:20

Comment: I dit it but its output other hour value, this is correctly? I never saw this kind of format before.

Comment: I didn't, somebody did it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and shortest way to goal this that I've found is:

```
DateTime.Parse("2013-05-04 13:12:20.123Z").ToUniversalTime()
```